# Run-time error 3075 syntax error customize error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I want to make customize error **"Nothing to Edit"** to my below code every time it shows

> Run-time error 3075

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAddService", acNormal, , "[ServiceID] = " & Me.cboServiceCode.Column(0).
```

Please help, I'm stuck in here. I'm not good at VBA.

Comment: A good starting place for you would be to research the following terms (separately): "VBA error handling" "On Error GoTo" You should find lots of information and code samples. Short description: error handling is how to customize how your code behaves when an error occurs. In VBA you start the error handler, then near the end of the code you have the code that gets called when an error is triggered. This code can, for example, display your custom message instead of the default message.

Comment: Read up, try something and if you have problems with that, use the [edit] link below your question to include that code and the description of what problems you're encountering to your Question.